# why an event handler doesnt work on the element that created on other function in javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my code, can i ask why the onclick event doesnt work for ini element which is the input.

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    img[0].onclick = function(event) {
        document.body.appendChild(div);
        var sion = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
        var val = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(sion[0], null);
        var mouseX = event.clientX;
        var mouseY = event.clientY;
        document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.top = (mouseY - 20) + "px";
        document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.left = (mouseX - 20) + "px";
        var ini = document.createElement("input");
        document.body.appendChild(ini);
        var hoftag = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.height;
        var result = hoftag.replace("px", "");
        result = parseInt(result);

        document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[1].style.top = (event.clientY - 20 + result) + "px";
        document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[1].style.left = (event.clientX - 40) + "px";
    };
    ini.onclick = function(event) {
        alert("hi");
    };
};
```

HTML:

```
<img src="jlin.jpg" id="image">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the scopes of the variables. Variable `ini` only lives within `img[0].onclick = function(event) {`. Please refer to this great picture from "JS ninja" book:

[image]

To fix your code, try:

```
img[0].onclick = function(event){
    ...
    var ini = document.createElement("input"); 
    document.body.appendChild(ini);
    ini.onclick = function(event){
        alert("hi");
    };
    ...
};
```

Comment: i thought i could define a global variable by simply omiting the var, but why after i omit the var the code still doesnt work

Comment: `ini.onclick = function(event){alert("hi");}};` is being executed right away, it won't wait till "ini" is defined (within onload handler). So, step-by-step: 1. undefined ini gets onclick handler (meaningless) 2. ini gets defined within onload. 3. User clicks on ini - no handler, nothing happens